# How can I scroll using the scroll wheel while editing a formula in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, scrolling, editing

Apparently it's not possible to scroll (with the mouse wheel) while editing a formula. I'm using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 (Version 1802).

My Research has revealed, that this was a problem after switching to Excel 2007. It must've worked before and did not work (the same way) in Excel 2007.

Unfortunately I do not know if this ever worked after that. A co-worker asked me about this and told me it used to work (a few weeks ago).

Is there any setting I'm missing? Is there a workaround?

#### What I've tried so far:

- double-clicking in cell (to activate formula-editing mode) and trying to scroll
- clicking in formula bar and trying to scroll
- a combinational order of the above
- while a cell is in focus, pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> to activate editing mode and trying to scroll <sup>(apparently was a workaround back when 2007 was released)</sup>
- middle clicking (scroll wheel) next to the cell I'm editing and using auto-scroll. **This works!**
- <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> works. Arrow keys don't (they're already used to navigate through the formula).

I hope everything is clear. If not, please let me know so I can clarify and maybe add a screenshot. It should be possible, I guess. It'd be quite useful to actually *see* the range I'm working with.

Comment: Alex,, your research list is almost correct. While use option 2 & 3 scrolling is not  possible, otherwise excel scrolls the sheet. I'm using both 2013 & 2016.

Comment: If you have problem with scroll wheel then I can suggest you the solution.

Comment: I knew I'd have a use for that Office 2003 install one day!  I'll see if my old NT2000 box has it on to confirm if the formula bar scroll is locked or not. I can still scroll under your other conditions.  Using Office 365 (Version 1708) on Win 10 (Version 10.0.16299)

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Thanks, that would be great! Please note that I am trying to scroll through the sheet (not the formula bar).

Comment: @RajeshS I'm sorry, I don't completely understand. What solution can you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

They say a picture is worth a thousand words, but `Superuser` says I also need to have at least 30 characters:  You won't be able to scroll if you click in the formula bar, but you should be able to if you edit in the cell.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I played with that setting before. It was *checked*. It just doesn't want to scroll (the sheet). Any idea why it won't?

Comment: @Alex Here it scrolls the sheet if the cursor is in the cell; not if in the formula bar; not at all if that option is deselected. I don't know why yours is behaving differently

Answer (score 0):

This feature did indeed function perfectly well until it was broken in all versions post Office 2003.

The scroll feature works if you <kbd>F2</kbd>, Double-Click, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, or start typing to edit within the cell, but will not work if you edit in the formula bar.

It can be fixed by installing the free to use [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm).

My recommendation is to open Excel before you install, so that when you click `Add`, `excel.exe` is there in the list and easy to find:

[image: Screenshot of "Choose Application" dialog]

Then click on `Settings` and tick `Make scroll wheel scroll window under cursor` and Office is back to normal.

[image: Screenshot of "Global Settings" dialog]